# Android Studio removes imports automatically

Tags: android, android-studio

Either of these imports I try to add gets removed automatically. What could be the reason?

```
import static com.example.cnsgn.uygulamam.anasayfaFragment.EXTRAURUNYORUM;
```

or

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of android studio called "Optimize imports on the fly". It removes unused imports automatically. It can be enabled/disabled from `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Auto Import -> Optimize Imports on the fly`

Comment: Tamam oldu, teşekkürler. @blackkara

Comment: Please use English lang. on this platform, to help others :-)
The problem you had : because the imported class is still written in your code. So whenever you try to import the actual one, then studio ignores and removes it. You must delete the usage in the code first.

Comment: I think it took care of the problem. Thanks @blackkara